# jQuery UI droppable - how does it work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, web

I have created a small page, and noticed some interesting behaviour.

When I drop an draggable element into a droppable area, the element goes on the right of the logo and not under it.

This is somehow strange, as the header and the droppable are two different classes.

[image]

How is this possible ? Thanks.

EDIT: The CSS.

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;

    background-color: gray;

    position: relative;

    z-index: 1;
}

header .logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;

    background-color: white;

    float: left;

    margin-left: 50px;

    position: relative;

    z-index: 1;
}

.droppable {
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;

    background-color: red;

    float: right;

    margin: 2.5%;

    position: relative;

    z-index: 0;
}

.draggable {
    width: 10%;
    height: 15%;

    float: left;

    margin: 5%;
}
```

The HTML: (the draggables are added dynamically by jquery)

```
<header>
    <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
    <div class="droppable">
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the CSS and HTML for the elements you are inquiring about.

Comment: I added the HTML and the CSS.

Comment: and the draggables? To me it looks like the draggable is floating on the logo. It also appears that the draggable has a very large border. Showing all of your work will lend more insight.

Comment: Scroll to see the draggables. This is all of my work which relates to this, the rest are just comments or tags in <head>. The draggable has a 5% margin, and a float left (the DRAGGABLE should float to the DROPPABLE, not to the logo).

Comment: I think I know why, there was no clear after the logo, and the float left was inherited by the draggable. Thanks for helping.

Comment: So, they were all CSS issues? I'll go ahead and put something in the "answer" so you can reference it later, if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have CSS issues. I would suggest looking at and manipulating the float around the `logo`, as well as the margin or border around the `draggables`.